# Adding image in rect in a custom view

Tags: android, xml

1st view is what I want to achieve

and 2nd view is what I have achieved

[image]

In the 2nd view both are Recf

Here is my `view` in `xml`

```
<com.example.app.utils.CustomCategoriesImageView
    android:id="@+id/customCategoriesImageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    app:bg_color="@color/colorLightBlue"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:square_angle="6"
    app:square_topMargin="50"
    app:square_rightMargin="80"
    app:square_color="@color/colorAccent"
    app:square_position_x="0"
    app:square_position_y="20"
    app:square_size="115dp" />
```

This is `attrs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomCategoriesImageView">
        <attr name="square_color" format="color"/>
        <attr name="square_size" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="square_angle" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="square_position_x" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="square_position_y" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="square_image" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="bg_color" format="color"/>
        <attr name="square_topMargin" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="square_rightMargin" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Here is my customView class `CustomCategoriesImageView extends View`

```
private static final int SQUARE_SIZE_DEF = 200;
private Rect rectImage;
private RectF rectBG;
private Paint paint,bgPaint;
private int squareColor, bgColor, squareSize squarePosX, squarePosY;
private int squareTopMargin, squareRightMargin, squareAngle, canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
private int image;
private float[] corners = new float[]{};
private Path path;

public CustomCategoriesImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    init(attrs);
}

public CustomCategoriesImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs);
}

private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set) {
    rectImage = new Rect();
    rectBG = new RectF();
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    bgPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    if (set == null) {
        return;
    }

    TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(set, R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView);

    squareColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView_square_color, Color.RED);
    bgColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView_bg_color, Color.YELLOW);
    squareSize = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView_square_size, SQUARE_SIZE_DEF);
    squarePosX = ta.getInt(R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView_square_position_x, getWidth() - 50);
    squarePosY = ta.getInt(R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView_square_position_y, getHeight() - 50);
    squareAngle = ta.getInt(R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView_square_angle, 10);
    image = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView_square_image, R.color.trans);
    squareTopMargin = ta.getInt(R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView_square_topMargin, 20);
    squareRightMargin = ta.getInt(R.styleable.CustomCategoriesImageView_square_rightMargin, 20);

    corners = new float[]{
            30, 30,        // Top left radius in px
            30, 30,        // Top right radius in px
            30, 30,          // Bottom right radius in px
            30, 30           // Bottom left radius in px
    };

    path = new Path();

    ta.recycle();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasWidth = w;
    canvasHeight = h;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    bgPaint.setColor(bgColor);
    rectBG.left = 0;
    rectBG.top = 0;
    rectBG.bottom = canvasHeight;
    rectBG.right = canvasWidth;

    path.addRoundRect(rectBG, corners, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.drawPath(path, bgPaint);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image);

    // first point, here square's top left point will be
    rectImage.left = canvasWidth - (squareSize - squareRightMargin);
    rectImage.top = canvasHeight - (squareSize - squareTopMargin);

    // second point, here square's bottom right point will be
    rectImage.right = canvasWidth - squarePosX;
    rectImage.bottom = canvasHeight - squarePosY;

    paint.setColor(squareColor);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(squareAngle, 100, 100);
    canvas.drawRect(rectImage, paint);
}
```

I didn't paste my whole class and constructors,
So

I m not worried about the text, as I can add TextView over my customView in ConstraintLayout
I m stuck at how to make this DarkBlue color Recq a image, and also change it's image dynamically on Runtime

Don't worry about **Gradient and Shadow**

Any help or push in the right direction will be awesome
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `drawBitmap()` to draw image inside another shape

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, rectBG, null);
// here bmp is a BitMap where I will setImage
// rectBG is a rectangle on the CustomView, you can see it in the Image I posted, it is the smaller one which is tiled
// first null can be replaces with a new Rect and last null can be replace with Paint
```

this is a method to send image from a class

```
// set image from Classes
public void setImage(int image) {
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image);
    postInvalidate();
    //here postInvalidate will replace the View with the new image data Async so if the image will take time to load, loading will not block the main thread
}
```

if you want to implemented something similar, you can use code from my question and add `setImage()` method to setImage in the tilted square or any other scenario

Hope this will help!